# Laravel8 - Validate a request with multiple wildcards

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-8

I've tried for the past 2 hours to validate a request with multiple wildcards and dot notation, but it won't work.

Basically, I have 2 levels of inputs in my form:

```html
<input type="text" name="user[0][name]" title="name of the user" />
<!-- Which works fine with validator -->

...

<input type="text" name="user[0][book][0][name]" title="name of one of the user's book" />
<!-- Which does not work with validator -->
```

My validator:

```php
return [
    'user.*.name' => 'required|min:1',
    'user.*.email' => 'required|min:1',
    'user.*.status' => 'required|min:1',
    'user.*.book.*.name' => 'required|min:1',
    'user.*.book.*.rating' => 'required|min:1'
];
```

Everything that validate user's information works fine, but it does not work when I'm trying to validate books data.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

For the ones who needs it, here is the actual code:

```html
<input type="text" 
    name="io[{{ $loop->index }}][name]"
    title="name of one of the Insertion Order" 
/>
<!-- Which works fine with validator -->

... In a sub-foreach loop ...

<input type="text" 
    name="io[{{ $loop->parent->index }}][li][{{ $loop->index }}][name]"
    title="name of one of the Insertion Order's Line Item's name" 
/>
<!-- Which does not work with validator -->
```

My validator:

```php
return [
    'campaign_name' => 'required|min:1',    // Static, works fine
    'campaign_total_budget' => 'required',  // Static, works fine
    'campaign_dates' => 'required',         // Static, works fine
    'io.*.name' => 'required|min:1',        // One wildcard, works fine
    'io.*.dates' => 'required|min:1',       // One wildcard, works fine
    'io.*.budget' => 'required|min:1',      // One wildcard, works fine
    'io.*.li.*.name' => 'required|min:1',   // Does not work
    'io.*.li.*.dates' => 'required|min:1',  // Does not work
    'io.*.li.*.budget' => 'required|min:1', // Does not work
];
```

Comment: Your validation rules state `books` as the array index name, but your HTML input just says `book`.

Comment: @repox Thanks for the super quick answer ! Unfortunately, this is just a mistake in the example code, not appearing on the actual code.

I will fix this and post the real code below the example one. Sorry for wasting your time mate.